# Using DropShadowEffect or BitmapEffect with Storyboard Target Property in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

how can I set the Storyboard.TargetProperty to DropShadowEffect or BitmapEffect in WPF XAML?

I'm trying to learn C# & XAML and I can't quite figure out how to use it. Also if anyone knows the properties that can be added to Storyboard.TargetProperty, please list them.

I have this piece of code I got from ChatGPT and it works but I needs a combination of XAML and C#;

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DropShadowEffect shadowEffect;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            shadowEffect = new DropShadowEffect
            {
                ShadowDepth = 10,
                Color = Colors.Black,
                Opacity = 0,
                BlurRadius =10,
                Direction = 270
            };

            button.Effect = shadowEffect;

            button.MouseEnter += Button_MouseEnter;
            button.MouseLeave += Button_MouseLeave;
        }

        private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            AnimateShadowOpacity(0.5);
        }

        private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            AnimateShadowOpacity(0);
        }

        private void AnimateShadowOpacity(double targetOpacity)
        {
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                To = targetOpacity,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)
            };

            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Opacity)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, button);

            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the XAML code;

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="18"></Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an equivalent XAML-only solution that also adds the missing `ContentPresenter` in the Button's `Template`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="18">
                        <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect
                    ShadowDepth="10"
                    Color="Black"
                    Opacity="0"
                    BlurRadius="10"
                    Direction="270"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"
                            Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"
                            Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"/>
</Grid>
```

Alternative Trigger:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"
                        Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0.5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity"
                        Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```